# Why isn't paperclip post processing working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, post-processing

Hello I've been looking around at all the various tutorials out there for Paperclip post processing but somehow I can not get the 'Make' method to invoke.

Take a look at line 36 here... http://pastie.org/private/epfgcxywhyh4wpmozypg

It uploads normally without any errors or warnings but I can never see the puts statement in the make method which tells me that this isn't being invoked.

EDIT

I can run this in the model without a problem and I get True,

```
def class_exists?(class_name)
   klass = Paperclip.const_get(class_name)
   return klass.is_a?(Class)
rescue NameError
   return false
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the FileContents class is being loaded?

Comment: Thats what I was trying to verify with the puts on line 36, I've also tried adding a debugger (ruby-debug) but it was never invoked hence why I'm wondering why its not being invoked.  Is there another way I can verify that the FileContents class is being loaded?

Comment: Try raising an exception on the first line of the file (raise 'here'). This will at least verify that the file is being loaded, which I think is a good place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two days ago I was facing the same problem. Here what I did to make it work:

Go to the command prompt and type: "which convert" command. This is ImageMagick command so if it says /usr/bin/convert then try adding

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

in your **config/environments/development.rb**. Remove /convert from what you get over there.

then change name of your file **file_contents.rb** to **paperclip_postprocess.rb** and put it into directory: **RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/paperclip_postprocess.rb**

You can cross check if your attachment is being processed or not by adding following lines in your model:

```
   before_post_process :before_post_process
   after_post_process :after_post_process

   def before_post_process
        puts "===========Before processing attachment==========="
   end

   def after_post_process
        puts "-----------After processign attachment------------"
   end
```

Take a look [here](http://pastie.org/1677911)

It worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this line in the Paperclip README:

> *NOTE: Because processors operate by turning the original attachment into the styles, no processors will be run if there are no styles defined.*

And looking at your paste, you define everything but a `:style` argument, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding  `:styles => { :chaff => [] } ` but same issue